# Google Play API for Querying My Apps, Editing My Apps, and Uploading New Apps

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Does Google offer a web service API for querying apps for my account, editing these apps, and uploading new ones?  If so, could someone provide a link?

The only thing I could find that would allow bulk operations is for Google Play IAP via a CSV file. Is there a bulk upload that exists for apps as well?

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API like that, sorry.

At best, you could write a script that authenticates with your credentials, and try and duplicate the POST and GET requests that come and go from the dev console web interface to try and duplicate the functionality.

Comment: Thanks! Do they offer a bulk app upload like they do for IAP items.

Comment: @user1707582 Afraid not. Bulk app upload is something a lot of people have asked for, but its not there.